# How to play a selected song from the list and pause the earlier song that was playing in the same list using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is just a sample code for the clarification.
Problem : Actually I can play the songs with the click but the problem is whenever I click song other song from the list or even the same song itself, it starts playing along with the song that was clicked earlier. Means on every click the songs are being played and the previous clicked songs are not paused.

I tried with some stuff but got headache. Please help me in any one have some solution :(

```js
var audio;
       $("#playlist li").click(function () {
          songname = $(this).text();
          audio = new Audio('mypath/songs/'+songname);
          audio.play();
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

the code does what you asked for. By clicking it simply triggers the song. You did not ask it to stop what's currently playing and start newly. In your click function you need to check whether audio is defined and if yes stop it. This will refer to a song which is already playin so you want to stop it. The code should be something like

```
       var audio;
       $("#playlist li").click(function () {
          //HERE you need to stop if a song is currently playing
          if (audio) {
              audio.stop();
          }
          songname = $(this).text();
          audio = new Audio('mypath/songs/'+songname);
          audio.play();
       });
```

Comment: just change `stop()` to `pause()` :)